# How to remove checkbox shadow on Safari

Tags: html, css, web, checkbox, styles

so I was trying to remove the box-shadow by typing the following:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

But for some reason, it doesn't let me select the checkbox now, how do I fix that?

Comment: Could you show us, preferably in a working snippet, how it doesn't allow you to select the box. For instance, have you set a height and width and also some action on the change event? setting appearance none does remove, well, the appearance but not the action (assuming the user can see the box in order to click on it).

Comment: Okay I actually managed to see the issue, I can change the styling when I select the checkbox, however I don't see the 'checkbox tick', any idea how to display it?

Comment: (I changed the styling using input:checked)

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want it to look like. Do whatever you want when you see the change event on the box (overlay a tick, change the color, tell the user they've clicked....).